# Prolog family relation how can i implement has child from one woman?

Tags: prolog

In a data I have basic facts with `gender(_name,_gender)` and `parent(_parent,_child)`, 
also I implement other rules.
How can I implement this rule:

```
has_child_from_one_woman(_person):-
```

I do something like this

```
has_child_from_one_woman(_person) :-
    parents(_mom,_person,_),
    not(parents(_other_mom,_person,__)),
    not(_mom \= _other_mom).
```

Is this true?
The 3rd parameter of parents is an underscore

```
parents(_mother,_father,_child) :-
    mother(_mother,_child),
    father(_father,_child).
```

Comment: From **only** one woman?

Comment: *at least one child* **or** *exactly one child*?

Comment: But then... can you have exactly one child from zero women or from more than one woman?

Comment: ok ok i mean at leats one child.

Comment: Why are you using all the underscores?

Comment: Probably is the best way to avoid having variables starting with capital letters.

Comment: @TudorBerariu what's the benefit in avoiding capitalized variables?

Answer (score 1):

Someone has children from only one woman if he has at least one child whose parent is some woman and there is no other child that has another woman as his/her mother. Translating that into Prolog...

```
has_children_from_one_woman(Man):-
    parent(Man, Child),
    parent(Woman, Child),
    gender(Woman, female),
    dif(Woman, Man),
    \+ (parent(Man, Child1),
        parent(Woman1, Child1),
        gender(Woman1, female),
        dif(Woman1, Man),
        dif(Woman1, Woman)).
```

The above rule is satisfied for the same `Man` several times if he has more than one child with that woman. You can put a cut at the end to avoid that.

Also, you can use `setof/3` to get the list of all women that have at least one child with `Man` and check if that list has only one element.

```
has_children_from_one_woman(Man):-
    setof(Woman,
          Child^(parent(Man, Child),
                 parent(Woman, Child),
                 gender(Woman, female),
                 dif(Woman, Man)),
          [_]).
```

Comment: `\+` means *it cannot pe proved that*. It is how you express negation under the closed world assumption (which is used in Prolog).

Comment: Yes, try to execute `X \== Y, X = a, Y = a. ` and `dif(X, Y), X = a, Y = a.`.